# Framerate problem on youtube like sites in fullscreen mode with 14.10

Tags: fullscreen

When I use full-screen mode in firefox, it seems that there is a framerate problem. 
Before update from 14.04 it worked fine.
In Chrome is OK.

Comment: Is this happening with both chrome and firefox or only with chrome?

Comment: if chrome only, if you have lots of unminimized chrome windows try minimizing some